# Welcome messages not allowed?

Tags: discussion

I recently had the opening message "Welcome to German SE" removed from an answer. While technically off-topic, my intent was to project a welcoming and friendly image of the site since it was the person's first question asked here. Is it a policy here not to include welcome messages for newcomers? I've been a regular on the site for about a year now, but I remember, when I first started, having the impression that it was a distinctly *un*friendly and *un*welcoming place. But having been a regular editor on Wikipedia has toughened my hide a bit and I soldiered on despite that. (The alternatives, such as Reddit, weren't that appealing either.) I have noticed though that nearly all of the first-time posters here seem to get discouraged and disappear, and I'd like to try to reverse that trend if possible. I thought one way would be to include a welcome message to first-time posters in comments or answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I appreciate the intention of establishing a friendly atmosphere (and don't recall, that I removed a welcome from an answer).

In all cases I remember, welcome messages were in in comments instead, which seems appropriate, since typically some addded hints seem beneficial, how the question can be improved as e.g. dropping salutations.

I consider this as a better place than the answer, since it is separated thematically as well as concerning the time scope of relevance and can  be removed later more easily.

So from my point of view a welcome is better placed into a comment than an answer, but *not allowed* seems too drastic even there.

Comment: Thanks. In this case I didn't see anything in the question I felt worth commenting on. (I know, that's kind of unusual for me.) In general, I think it's always a good idea to say "Welcome" to a newcomer in the comments if you're going to suggest some improvement in the question, a reference the asker should have checked before posting, etc.